# Tables - Worksheet_Change Fires Multiple Times

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to capture the worksheet change event when a table heading is cleared by the user.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
application.EnableEvents = False    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange) Is Nothing Then
        msgbox "Hello"
    end if
application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub
```

If the user presses "delete" to clear a non-default heading name on the table, Excel automatically replaces the blank heading with the default heading name (eg. "Column1").  This seems to cause the worksheet change event to run multiple times.  I'd like to figure out a way to have this event run only once when the user clears the a heading.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround for this is to add an assertion at the beginning of your event, that checks that the target cell does not already contain a default column name.

I would do this with a simple `if` and `like` statement, which catches when a heading begins with "Column" and exits the event using `Exit Sub`. You could do all of this in one simple line of code. Something like...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.value Like "Column*" Then Exit Sub
application.EnableEvents = False    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange) Is Nothing Then
        msgbox "Hello"
    end if
application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub
```

This code is admittedly untested but it should provide you with a good base to start from.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced exact same problem. The Worksheet_Change event is fired second time (and two times only) after switching back Application.EnableEvents = True (like It'd be queeed or something).
The solution is to add global boolean var to control event suppressing:

```
Option Explicit

Private suppressEvents As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' add additional conditionals here to filter out cases that don't run many times

'this one prevents from running two times
If Not suppressEvents Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'setting this is mendatory since, the change event would run in loop until crash
        If example Is Nothing Then
            suppressEvents = True
            Application.Undo
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    suppressEvents = False
End If

End Sub
```